# Finding limit of a function when limit of its logarithm is given

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a function and $g(x) = \log(f(x))$. Show that if $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = L$ then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = e^L$. I'm pretty sure this question has already been answered, but I can not find it online.

Comment: Use \lim and \log to write $\lim$ and $\log$ properly. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I have fixed the MathJax this time, you may click on the "edited" to see what changes I made and then use MathJax in a better way next time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be
$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)= \lim_{x\to a} e^{\log(f(x))}=\lim_{x \to a} e^{g(x)}=e^L$$

Comment: What is used here is that $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous which means that $\lim_{x\to a} e^{g(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\to a} g(x)}.$

Answer (score 1):

If you take the antilog with base e on $g(x) = ln(f(x))$ you get $e^{g(x)}=f(x)$.

Now we know that $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = L$.
Using these equations,

$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \lim_{x\to a}e^{g(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)} = e^L
$$

This should be your proof.